# How to exclude certain numbers from sequence?

Tags: r

I only want to catch fish that are over 20lbs. So the times in the sequence where the fish is 12-20 I want to throw back.

```
Fish <- sample(x=c(7,4,2), size=1000, prob = c(.1,.6,.3),replace = TRUE) #Dialy Catch 
Weight <- seq(30, 35, 18) #avg ILBs per fish 
DailyLBs <- Fish * (Weight > 20) #Dialy LBS of Fish
```

Comment: It is not clear what your expected output and meaning of `Weight` vector

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your code is doing what you want.
`seq(30, 35, 18)`
doesn't make sense. so I'm not clear what's happening.

anyway, assuming your fish weights are:

```
fish_weight <- sample(12:40, 10)
```

you can find either the index of the weights or just filtering the weights this way:

```
fish_weight[fish_weight > 20]
which(fish_weight > 20)
```

the total weight would then be:

```
sum(fish_weight[fish_weight > 20])
```

Comment: seq(30, 35, 18) The average fish is between 30-35 lbs with an SD of 18

Comment: `seq(30, 35, 18)` generates a sequence of numbers between 30, and 35 with an increment of 18. meaning you will get a sequence of one number: 30. run `seq(3, 11, 2)` and see the result.

Comment: @CQtiandi `seq(30, 35, 18)` generates a sequnce. The usage is  `seq(from,to,by = )` ([see here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/seq).In your case you create a sequence that should starts at 30, ends at 35 and with steps of size 18. I guess this is not what you expected